# Rails redirect after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I have

```
def destroy 
    Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:info] = "Event deleted" 
    redirect_to :back
end
```

And I am able to delete an item from 2 different views. On one view it is a list of items, so I can use `:back` and reload the same page. But the other delete is on the view of the item to delete, so once it's gone I want to `redirect_to` somewhere different.

My question is how do I tell Rails a different `redirect_to` path depending on where the `destroy` method is coming from?

Just as a test, I tried using an if statement based on a body class in the html, but the instance variable is not carried into the destroy method (I assume) as it didn't work. e.g.

```
def destroy
    if @body_class == 'one page'
        Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:info] = "Event deleted" 
        redirect_to :back
    elsif @body_class == 'a different page'
        Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:info] = "Event deleted" 
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the params with destroy link. If link is on list, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', event_path(event, :from=>"list"), :method=>:delete %>
```

If on object page:

```
 <%= link_to 'destroy', event_path(event), :method=>:delete %>
```

And in controller:

```
def destroy 
    Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:info] = "Event deleted" 
    if params[:from]=='list'
    redirect_to :back
    else
    redirect_to root_url 
end
```